# django updateview not showing existing data to form

Tags: django

update is working but template form is not showing existing data. django updateview not showing existing data to form. when update page is showing only existing file is showing but object data is not showing. updateview cannot send existing data to form

***view.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from .forms import BookForm
from .models import Book

from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class BookUpdate(UpdateView):
model = Book
form_class = BookForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('class_book_list')
template_name = 'updatebook.html'
```

***model.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Book(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='books/pdfs/')
cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='books/covers/', null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Book

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ('title', 'author', 'pdf', 'cover')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from .  import views

urlpatterns = [
path('books/', views.book_list, name='book_list'),
path('books/upload/', views.upload_book, name='upload_book'),
path('books/<int:pk>/',views.delete_book, name='delete_book'),
path('class/books/',views.BookListView.as_view(), name='class_book_list'),
path('class/books/upload/',views.UploadBookView.as_view(), name='class_upload_book'),
path('class/books/update/<int:pk>/',views.BookUpdate.as_view(), name='class_update_book'),'''
```

**updatebook.html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Upload Book to Database</h2>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form | crispy}}
<button type="submit" >Update</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

html form cannot display existing data from database
please help

Answer (score 1):

Make your method to GET i.e. (method="GET") in the form from where you are requesting the UpdateView page.